# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bayesnet'

Tags: python, import, pip, importerror, error-code

I'm trying to use the OpenBayes module, but the problems start from the very first step :'(
When I try to import from OpenBayes
I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Мари\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\OpenBayes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from bayesnet import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bayesnet'
```

UPD: While installing (from .exe file) for py2 i gor error: "could not set a key value" (not a python error, but in dialog window)

I tried using pip install from console, but still get errors there.

```
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\CD3B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m4nnwa4o\OpenBayes\
```

Also not sure which py (2 or 3) is used when i type a command from console(

(Sorry for all that stupis questions)

Comment: Try running it on python2, library is abandoned and not ported for py3.

Comment: @Aki003 thank you!! Do you know why it is abandoned and is there something similar for py3?

Comment: @Aki003 with py2 it says "could not set a key value" and finishes the installation ='(

Comment: Please update the question with the error that you got while running on py2

Answer (score 0):

You should

`from OpenBayes import *`
or
 `from OpenBayes import BNet`

Here is an example demonstrating it's usage:
https://github.com/willasaywhat/OpenBayes-Fork/blob/master/Examples/bn_asia.py

Comment: That's just what I entered to get that:

Comment: from OpenBayes import BNet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Мари\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\OpenBayes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bayesnet import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bayesnet'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I created a directory with the same name as the root folder (within the root folder). Python then referred Its import calls to the src directory and not the folder. I also changed the python interpreter to a virtual (anaconda.exe), as the python install did not contain many of the modules that were being called by the application (flask, etc)

It's a weird workaround, but it worked for me. Hope this helps